# access Android system images in QML

Tags: android, qml, qt-quick

Is there any way to use system Android resources (images) in QML code?

Like images I see in ANDROID_SDK_DIR\platforms\android-xx\data\res\drawable-yyyy?

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true

   Image {
       source: "file://android/image/drawable/ic_menu_more" // don't work
   }
}
```

Comment: May be you app has no enough permissions to read file system files?

Answer (score 1):

Qt Quick Controls' [Android style](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/12/03/native-android-style-in-qt-5-4/) [already does this](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/bbe7cac483b600cf6825deb4c73b93d769939bfc:src/controls/Styles/Android), and I believe that it's much more complicated than referring to an image on the file system - it involves some Java code, at the very least.

If you want to do something similar, I'd suggest checking out the links above; there's too much code to show here.